# Why can't I connect to Sharepoint Odata Feed in PowerBI?

Tags: sharepoint, odata, powerbi

I have an api from Sharepoint and I want to access the data from Power BI via an Odata Feed. But when I do so I get an "Access to the ressource is forbidden". I don't get to choose which autenthification method I want to use, like I do with other apis (not Sharepoint). The api work fine though when I try the same thing in excel. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then this steps will help to achieve your ask,

1. Go  to Data Source Setting under Edit Queries ribbon pane on Power BI Desktop.
   [image]
2. Chose Data Source then Click on Edit Permission to change permission level.

[image]

Comment: Hi. The problem is that I don't even get a query. I choose OData Feed in "Get Data" and then I write the url and when I press "OK" it says "Unable to connect. We encountered a problem while trying to connect. Details: access to the resource is forbidden"

Comment: Not getting to a query editor but pointing you to click on edit query text will open an option to choose data source settings and then choose global data source and you can follow the steps above.

Comment: Thanks @Mboolean. I can follow your guide for other data sources, but the Sharepoint OData feed is not there for some reason.

Comment: If there's not too much in there, try clearing all permissions to see if you get prompted for credentials the next time you run the query. Depending on your systems, try different options such as *windows* or *organizational account*. You are using the API at the endpoint _vti_bin/listdata.svc?

Comment: If you could please help me with my related problem where I get error back  even before asked for credentials.
The WWW-Authenticate header doesn't contain a valid authorization URI. Header value:
 'Basic realm="https://axprodcus1.analytics.visualstudio.com/",Bearer,TFS-Federated'.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Using-OData-Feed-Azure-DevOps-Analytics-URL-working-in-browser/m-p/892368#M427780

Answer (score 1):

I just tried one of example Odata url provided by Mircorsoft.
I tried to fecth data in PowerBI and it worked fine for me without any issue.

https://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/

I belive you are facing this issue as error says, you might not have set Authentication for your API or your Odata feed is not in correct format.

I tired another freely available Odata feed in PowerBI and it gave me error stating Odata is not correct.

https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/

> The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid. Error: The
>   metadata document could not be read from the message content.
>   UnexpectedXmlAttribute : The attribute 'ConcurrencyMode' was not
>   expected in the given context. : (1, 2043)

Summary: your authentication for API is not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for answers. The problem was my authentication for the API, but I wanted to be able to edit the credentials to use another user and password anyway. Since powerBI was setup to use Windows credentials I never came to that point though. I solved it by making a new powerBI file and chose "edit query", where I entered the query from my collegue, that had perfect access. Then I could edit permissions in the data source settings.